# How to add a toolbar over GMSMapView

Tags: ios, dictionary, toolbar

I am making an iPhone application that uses a GMSMapView and I want to be able to add a toolbar on top of the map. This is my code:

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController
{
GMSMapView *mapView_;
id<GMSMarker> myMarker;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

// You don't need to modify the default initWithNibName:bundle: method.

- (void)loadView
{
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:30.616083 longitude:-96.338908 zoom:13];

mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView_.delegate = self;
self.view = mapView_;

GMSMarkerOptions *options = [[GMSMarkerOptions alloc] init];
options.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(30.616083, -96.338908);
options.title = @"College Station";
options.snippet = @"Texas";
[mapView_ addMarkerWithOptions:options];
}

#pragma mark - GMSMapViewDelegate
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
[myMarker remove];

NSLog(@"You tapped at %f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
GMSMarkerOptions *marker = [[GMSMarkerOptions alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
marker.title = @"Tap Event";
// (icon for marker) marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"house"];
myMarker = [mapView_ addMarkerWithOptions:marker];
}

@end
```

In my storyboard i have a toolbar but I do not know how to get it to be displayed over the GMSMapView. Im new to iOS and have searched for solutions online but haven't had any luck with GMSMapView.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the view to the mapView_, the view made in StoryBoard is overriden. I've added a toolbar with an Segmented Control and an button using the following code:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

UINavigationBar  *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenBounds.size.width, 44)];
UINavigationItem *navItems = [[UINavigationItem alloc]init];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonRight = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(SettingsButtonPressed)];
UISegmentedControll *segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Opt1",@"Opt2",@"Opt3", nil]];
UIImage *imageSettings= [UIImage imageNamed:@"36-toolbox.png"];

[segControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
[segControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
[segControl setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 150, 32)];
[segControl addTarget:self action:@selector(KiesVC:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[barButtonRight setImage:imageSettings];

[navItems setRightBarButtonItem:barButtonRight];
[navItems setTitleView:segControl];

[navBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navItems] animated:NO];
```

You then add the toolbar by calling :

[self.view addSubview:navBar];

Hope it helps